# Forcing a sql query to return results

Tags: sql, t-sql

Here is my SQL:

```
-- Order information
SELECT ISNULL(p.PaymentAmt, 0) AS PaymentAmt, o.TaxAmt, o.PostAmount, o.OrderDate, o.PublicNotes, u.userid, PostAmount + TaxAmt AS Total, PostAmount - PaymentAmt AS Due
FROM Orders o 
INNER JOIN Payment p ON p.OrderID = o.OrderID
INNER JOIN Users u  ON o.EnteredBy = u.UserKey
Where o.OrderID = 5267
```

Right now for this specific OrderID it returns 0 rows just the column headers.  Is there a way to force this to return 0's for the value and empty strings for the rest?

Comment: It returns 0 records because there is no order with OrderID=5267? Btw, `AND o.EnteredBy = u.UserKey` is redundant since you've already defined this contraint in the `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I know that, the question was how to force it to return results.  When no order exists I need it to return 0's for all of the values and empty strings for the rest.

Comment: That was a question not a statement. That there's no order with the given id is just one reason why no rows are returned. Another is that the order's EnteredBy-user does not exist(f.e. is `null`).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Just because you put a question mark at the end of a sentence does not a question make. =p  But yes, there is no orderID associated with it.

Comment: The EnteredBy does exist, if I create an order it will show the information, but I need to fake it when no order is created until one is created.  Hopefully that makes sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it should give you desired results :

```
WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT ISNULL(p.PaymentAmt, 0) AS PaymentAmt, o.TaxAmt, o.PostAmount,  
   o.OrderDate, o.PublicNotes, u.userid, PostAmount + TaxAmt AS Total, PostAmount -    
    PaymentAmt AS Due 
    FROM Orders o  
    INNER JOIN Payment p ON p.OrderID = o.OrderID 
    INNER JOIN Users u  ON o.EnteredBy = u.UserKey 
    Where o.OrderID = 5267 
    AND o.EnteredBy = u.UserKey )
SELECT CTE1.*
FROM CTE1
UNION ALL
SELECT 0,0, NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM CTE1)
```

Comment: This gives me the following error: `Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Invalid object name 'CTE'.`

Comment: @James Wilson: Already fixed, it was misprint (should be `CTE1`)

Comment: Ahh must have missed it, now it is working.  Going to play with it a little bit.

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
SELECT ISNULL(p.PaymentAmt, 0) AS PaymentAmt, o.TaxAmt, o.PostAmount, 
       o.OrderDate, o.PublicNotes, u.userid, 
       PostAmount + TaxAmt AS Total, PostAmount - PaymentAmt AS Due
FROM Orders o 
  INNER JOIN Payment p ON  p.OrderID = o.OrderID
                       AND o.OrderID = 5267        --- condition moved here
  INNER JOIN Users u  ON o.EnteredBy = u.UserKey
  RIGHT JOIN (SELECT 1 dummy) trick ON 1=1         --- this line was added

---  AND o.EnteredBy = u.UserKey                   --- this is redundant
```

Comment: I could not get this to work even after the edit.  It still returns 0 rows after the right join was added.

Comment: There we go, that made it work.  I'm not sure which way is better but they both work.